# MongoDB - From User collection where email = example@example.com, get everything from "orders" array

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

It seems like a simple thing, but i'm struggling with it.

I want to find an user through email, which will be given in the req.params. Then I want to retrieve all orders that the user has made. I don't want to filter them, I just want all the content from orders array.

The request looks like this right now. I managed to get all users and orders where the order.ticker is Nio. But it's now quite what I require.

My goal is to display all the orders that the person has made in a list

```
exports.getOrders = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    email
  } = req.params;

  try {
    const user = await User.find({email})

    if (!user) {
      console.log('Sorry that user does not exist')
    }

    const userOrders = await User.find({"orders.ticker" : "Nio"})


    res.status(200).send(userOrders).json({
      message: `User: ${user} found!`
    });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: error.message
    })
  }
}; // end of getOrders
```

This is example data from mongoDb:
[MongoDB collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUqfc.png)

Comment: looks like you just need a `$project` and keep only that array of orders but i am not sure, if you can give your data in text json, and the expected results in text json, so people can help easier

Comment: You can use the [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) method to get a user's data by the email. The returned value will have the `orders` array field (which you can use in your program).

Comment: In the `const user = ` line, you already retrieved the entire document from the server, including the array.  Wouldn't it be more efficient to filter the array on the client side (perhaps with Array.filter), instead of retrieving it from the server all over again?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
module.exports.getOrders = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userOrders = await User.find({"orders.ticker" : req.params.email})

    if (!userOrders) {
      return res.status(200).send({ message: "User has no orders" })
    }


    res.status(200).send(userOrders)

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: error
    })
  }
}; // end of getOrders
```

Explanation:

so i am not checking if the user exist its ok if you do but its not neccesary and simply finding orders. if user has no order it will say user has no order. and finally if user has order i am sending it. also, you were adding `josn()` after `send()` data has been send and shouldn't use it

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this returns an empty array. @prasad_ answer was what did it for me so thanks a lot!